# Disable saving vector layer in QGIS, especially in DXF and KML file?

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, export, disable

Can you help me on how to disable the exportation of vector layers especially in AutoCAD DXF, DBF File and ESRI Shapefile?

Comment: You're trying to get QGIs to be a viewer only ?

Comment: QGIS doesn't force you to export in any particular format. Are you trying to create a version of QGIS with those export options missing? To make it simpler for users?

Comment: my gis vectors are connected to mysql i would like to know if there is a way to secure the vectors loaded on qgis, i want that other users cant get or export the vectors.

Comment: So do you want: all your data in a mysql database; some people to have read and write access to the mysql DB (eg you); some people to have read access only to the DB; some people who do have read access to not be able to save the data outside the DB?

Comment: The big problem is that it is *very* hard to stop people who have read access to data (for a valid reason) saving that data. The games companies spend millions on anti-duplication tech but that gets cracked. Do you care that much?

Answer (score 5):

The only way would be to use WMS to view data so that no data is directly loaded to QGIS, and use wfs with featureid if required to edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually disable the Save As vector functionality altogether in QGIS but this will only work provided that QGIS is running on Windows. It will be useful in an enterprise environment where the user doesn't have access to the Registry.

1. In QGIS go to Configuration > Customization > Tick the checkbox Enable customization.
2. Edit the system registry to set the following key to false:
   `hkey_current_user/Software/QGIS/CUSTOMIZATION/QgsVectorLayerSaveAsDialogBase/buttonBox`

You can still right-click and select Save As but the dialogue box doesn't have the OK button.

Source: [Prevent export to shapefile from postgis table in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203874/prevent-export-to-shapefile-from-postgis-table-in-qgis/203877). I tested it on QGIS 2.x

Comment: @CarloGaffud you're most welcome. If the solution worked out for you, you can accept the answer to let other people know that it works.