# Qgis 3 & table PostGIS : how to prevent/disabled save as (basic users)

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, postgresql

With PostGIS and **QGIS 3** (Windows), what ways can deactivate/prevent for simple PostGIS users (PostgreSQL connection role only SELECT rights on tables), the functionality offered by QGIS to export from the PostGIS table (via right-click "save as/export") toward file formats?

There is this following post dealing with topic. But it says nothing about QGIS 3.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/203943/35117

With QGIS 3, where could we find the path pointing to Configuration > customization > enable custom for all? According to the post, Seems to be the first step.

Comment: There was not anything QGIS-specific about that Answer.

Comment: Nothing else comes into my mind but not to deliver any vectors for your users. Render them into raster maps with a WMS server.

Comment: No because unfortunatly, Regarding the usefull  link,( i have edited the URL/anchor): https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/203943/35117
With QGIS 3, where could we find the path pointing to Configuration > customization > enable custom for all.